# Substring from the end in generic way in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, substring

Assume we have such strings.

```
const del = 'Deleted'
const str1 = 'clean.Deleted'
const str2 = 'get.clean.Deleted'
const str3 = 'cl.Deleted'
```

And I need return every time str1, str2,str3 without `.Deleted`

It is work for me:

```
any_string.substr(0, (any_string.length - del.length-1))
```

Do we have a more generic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `.Deleted` is always `.Deleted`, then `string.replace`

```
const newString = oldString.replace('.Deleted', '')
```

You can replace that with RegExp if you only want `.Deleted` that happens at the end.

```
const newString = oldString.replace(/\.Deleted$/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use slice with negative value for slicing from last(.Deleted length is 8, so use -8)

```
str.slice('.Deleted',-8)
```

**JS:**

```js
const del = 'Deleted'
const str1 = 'clean.Deleted'
const str2 = 'get.clean.Deleted'
const str3 = 'cl.Deleted'

console.log(str1.slice('.Deleted',-8))
console.log(str2.slice('.Deleted',-8))
console.log(str3.slice('.Deleted',-8))
```

**Note:** This solution works only if the .Deleted is always at the last part of the string